# React-Native: Custom Child objects vs. Object array in Parent's props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, parent-child

When creating customizable reusable React components, what is best practice regarding definition of children?

For instance: 
I'm created a reusable customizable option-fan component. I also wanted to be able to customize/control aspects of the child buttons of this parent option-fan, so I made a Child component as well.

So implementation would ideally look like this:

```
 <FanButton 
                  diameter={100}
                  staggerDelay={300}
                  position={ {x: 100, y: 100} }
                  icon={}
                  children={3} >
                  <ChildButton/>
                  <ChildButton/>
                  <ChildButton/>
 </FanButton>
```

My question is: is it appropriate or even necessary to bring the child element into the equation in this manner, or could/should it be brought in as an array of objects in a prop of Option-Fan?

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself this question, am I expecting every places where I put `FanButton` to have exactly 3 `ChildButton`? Or its random depending on where the `FanButton` sits?

If your answer is yes, every `FanButton` will definitely only have 3 `ChildButton`, then just put `ChildrenButton` directly inside `FanButton`. Generally we don't include `ChildrenButton` inside `FanButton` to ensure scalability

Comment: Agreed with your answer..!

Comment: @NeelGala you can upvote the answer as a token of appreciation if you're agree with the answer :)

Comment: the idea was to have any number of children handled by the parent, my question was more about whether I should add x children by adding <Child> elements or by giving the parent of prop for the number of desired children to be handled inside the Parent class. it seems, to maintain the level of control & customization of the children, the former is most logical to me, but I could be wrong.